# Dockerfile - ENTRYPOINT don´t save variables

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, curl, dockerfile

I have the next Dockerfile for my Ubuntu container

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install.
RUN \
  sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt-get install -y byobu curl git htop man unzip vim wget jq && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /root

# Define default command.
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]

#First create an Auth token for Sonar server
ENTRYPOINT [ "token=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "name=WindowsTokenFinal" -u admin:pass 10.0.0.2:9000/api/user_tokens/generate | jq -r '.token')"]
#
# #Save session cookies
ENTRYPOINT ["COOKIEJAR="$(mktemp)""]
#
# #Generate crumb of Jenkins
ENTRYPOINT ["CRUMB=$(curl -u "admin:pass" --cookie-jar "$COOKIEJAR" "http://10.0.0.3:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,%22:%22,//crumb)")"]
#
# #Create Credentials on Jenkins Server
ENTRYPOINT ["curl -X POST -u "admin:pass" --cookie "$COOKIEJAR" -H "$CRUMB" 'http://10.0.0.3:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' --data-urlencode 'json={"": "0","credentials": {"scope": "GLOBAL","id": "WindowsAutoToken","description": "Automatically generated sonar token from windows","secret": "$Token", "$class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl"}}'"]
```

The first problem is that it only executes the last ENTRYPOINT, but if I run the first one only, the

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "token=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "name=WindowsTokenFinal" -u admin:pass 10.0.0.2:9000/api/user_tokens/generate | jq -r '.token')" ]
```

It doesn´t save the token variable.

If I execute the commands inside the container there is no problem and it works perfectly, but I need to run this commands once the container is up without running them by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern I've found useful is to use `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script that does first-time setup, and then use `CMD` to actually say what the main process is.  This will let you do whatever you need to do in the entrypoint wrapper script, and then run the main process as a foreground job.

With what you've shown in the Dockerfile, you could package that up into a shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#First create an Auth token for Sonar server
token=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "name=WindowsTokenFinal" -u admin:pass 10.0.0.2:9000/api/user_tokens/generate | jq -r '.token')

#Save session cookies
COOKIEJAR="$(mktemp)"

#Generate crumb of Jenkins
CRUMB=$(curl -u "admin:pass" --cookie-jar "$COOKIEJAR" "http://10.0.0.3:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,%22:%22,//crumb)")

#Create Credentials on Jenkins Server
curl -X POST -u "admin:pass" --cookie "$COOKIEJAR" -H "$CRUMB" 'http://10.0.0.3:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' --data-urlencode 'json={"": "0","credentials": {"scope": "GLOBAL","id": "WindowsAutoToken","description": "Automatically generated sonar token from windows","secret": "$Token", "$class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl"}}'

# Launch the main container process
exec "$@"
```

Then in the Dockerfile, `COPY` this script in, set it as the `ENTRYPOINT`, and set the `CMD` to the single process you want the container to run (probably not an interactive shell).

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["my_application", "--foreground"]
```

Remember that a container runs only one process.  If you have both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` directives, [the `CMD` gets passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), and if you have multiple `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, only the last one takes effect and the previous ones are ignored.  Also remember that the [JSON-array syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) doesn't do any sort of processing or substitution, so things like `$(subprocess)` invocations don't work with that syntax; also that the JSON-array syntax can be picky around things like nested quotes and there's no feedback if you get it wrong, Docker just silently falls back to [shell-command form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example).

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is a great idea!